# adding values and keeping a running total

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have tried to figure this out but unsure on what to do next. what i am trying to do is have an array of values, and a starting value, ie

startingvalue =2

array = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9

what i need returning is,

- 2 which is (2x1)
- 6 which is value above x array value 3
- 30 which is value above x array value 5
- 210 which is value above x array value 7
- 1890 which is value above x array value 9

this is what i have done so far, but it returns

- 2
- 6
- 10
- 14
- 18

and doesnt use the previous value to do the multiplication

```
var startingValue = prompt("What Is The Starting Value");

var VXP = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];

var text = "";

var i;

for (i = 0; i < VXP.length; i++) {
    result = text += VXP[i] * startingValue + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: `var resultArray = VXP.map(function (item) { startingValue *= item; return startingValue; });`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this-

```
for (i = 0; i < VXP.length; i++) {
    startingValue *= VXP[i];
    result = text += startingValue + "<br>";
}
```

That will update the previous value.